# How to access target of std::tr1::shared_ptr in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb, shared-ptr, tr1

How can I access target of a std::tr1::shared_ptr in GDB. This doesn't work:

```
(gdb) p sharedPtr->variableOfTarget
```

If I try with the pointer object itself (`p sharedPtr`) I get something like this:

```
$1 = std::tr1::shared_ptr (count 2) 0x13c2060
```

With a normal pointer I can do `p *ptr` and get all the data or `p ptr->variable` for just one variable.

I'm on Centos 6.5, GCC 4.4.7-4.el6 and GDB 7.2-64.el6_5.2.

Comment: Which compiler and stdlib are you using? Also which version of GDB?

Comment: @Alastair sorry! Updated my question.

Comment: have you tried `(gdb) p sharedPtr.get()`?

Comment: @Raydel Miranda That worked! Thanks very much! I'll add answer in a moment.

Comment: I wasn't able to answer my own question yet, since I have too little reputation. This is what worked: `p (*sharedPtr.get())` prints contents of the target object and `p (*sharedPtr.get())->variableOfTarget` will print a single variable.

Funny thing is though that if you leave out the parentheses like this `p *sharedPtr.get()` it will also advance execution of the program. Can someone explain why is that?

Comment: `unique_ptr`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798601/how-to-debug-c11-code-with-unique-ptr-in-ddd-or-gdb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with

```
(gdb) p (*sharedPtr.get())
```

that function returns the a pointer to the object owned by the smart pointer.

Comment: You have to use asterisk in front to get access to the pointer target and for some reason also parentheses like this: `(*sharedPtr.get())`. See my comment to the question.

Comment: If I use this solution I get
`(gdb) p (*self.get())
You can't do that without a process to debug.`

Answer (score 34):

ptr->get() not always work.

when i try ptr->get(), gdb complains for: can not resolve method ***:get() to any overloaded instance

I eventually go to /usr/include/ to find the source code of shared_ptr to see the private member.

It turns out to be

ptr._M_ptr

It works for me. Source code works for everyone.

Comment: You meant ptr.get()  right?  I think the operator `->` is not what you want use here.

Comment: ptr->get() means *ptr.get().

Comment: Nop, is not the same, `ptr->get()` is an attemp to call the `get` function from whatever the shared_ptr is pointing to, and `*ptr.get()` is dereferencing that pointer.  The `.` operator has preference here.  `*ptr.get()` is the same that `*(ptr.get())`.

Answer (score 8):

Answer first:

```sh
p *frame._M_ptr # frame is the shared_ptr's name
```

I tried `p (*frame.get())`, but it didn't work(frame is my shared_ptr name)

```
(gdb) p frame
$4 = std::shared_ptr (count 2, weak 0) 0x2ea3080
(gdb) p (*frame.get())
Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined
```

then I tried to get what's in this shared_ptr, then I found this

```
(gdb) p frame.
_M_get_deleter  __shared_ptr    operator*       reset           unique          ~shared_ptr     
_M_ptr          get             operator->      shared_ptr      use_count       
_M_refcount     operator bool   operator=       swap            ~__shared_ptr
```

I used it's _M_ptr field, it worked.

```
(gdb) p *frame._M_ptr 
$5 = {
...
}
```

I used std::shared_ptr, and gdb 7.6.