# How to view the internal data of a smart pointer inside gdb?

Tags: c++, linux, printing, gdb, shared-ptr

I've got test program like below:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<int> si(new int(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Debug it:

```
(gdb) l
1   #include<memory>
2   #include<iostream>
3   using namespace std;
4   
5   int main()
6   {
7       shared_ptr<int> si(new int(5));
8       return 0;
9   }
10  
(gdb) b 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400bba: file testshare.cpp, line 8.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/x/cpp/x01/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at testshare.cpp:8
8       return 0;
(gdb) p si
$1 = std::shared_ptr (count 1, weak 0) 0x614c20
```

It only prints out the pointer type information of `si`, but how to get the value stored in it (in this case `5`)?
How can I check the internal content of `si` during debugging?

Comment: What do you mean with *"the value store in si"*? The value of the `int` `si` points to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access target of std::tr1::shared\_ptr in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917556/how-to-access-target-of-stdtr1shared-ptr-in-gdb) | `unique_ptr`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798601/how-to-debug-c11-code-with-unique-ptr-in-ddd-or-gdb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
p *si._M_ptr
```

Now, this assumes that you're using `libstdc++.so`, given the output for `p si`.

Alternatively, you could use the value `0x614c20` directly (from your output):

```
p {int}0x614c20
```

Both should display the value `5`.

Answer (score 3):

> but how to get the value stored in it

You will have to cast raw pointer to actual pointer type stored in `std::shared_ptr`. Use `whatis` to know what the actual pointer type is.

```
(gdb) p si
$8 = std::shared_ptr (count 1, weak 0) 0x614c20
(gdb) whatis si
type = std::shared_ptr<int>
(gdb) p *(int*)0x614c20
$9 = 5
```