# how to debug shared_ptr with codeblocks

Tags: gdb, codeblocks, shared-ptr

It cannot display point deference context. Codeblocks verison is 16.01, TDM-gcc is 5.1.0-3, gdb is 7.9.1 which includes Python "pretty printers". It can display vector smartly, but shared_ptr seems not worked. I attach the img .[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view the internal data of a smart pointer inside gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420814/how-to-view-the-internal-data-of-a-smart-pointer-inside-gdb)

Comment: thanks,I hope to use codeblocks .Is there any methods in codeblocks to display it.