# Print gdb share_ptr from set

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb

How I can print value of share pointer stored in set.
  Print gdb share_ptr from C++ set.

```
    p field_set
$30 = std::set with 5 elements = {
  [0] = std::shared_ptr (count 2, weak 0) 0x862030,
  [1] = std::shared_ptr (count 2, weak 0) 0x863630,
  [2] = std::shared_ptr (count 2, weak 0) 0x863710,
  [3] = std::shared_ptr (count 2, weak 0) 0x8637f0,
  [4] = std::shared_ptr (count 2, weak 0) 0x8638d0
```

As you can see share_ptr are stored in C++ set value. **How I can print value ?**

I have already tried below input, its not working :

```
1.  p *(field_set)._M_ptr 
  //No symbol "driverl" in current context.
2.  p *(field_set[0])._M_ptr
   //No symbol "operator[]" in current context.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view the internal data of a smart pointer inside gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420814/how-to-view-the-internal-data-of-a-smart-pointer-inside-gdb)

Comment: @ ks1322: I am looking for printing value of share pointer stored inside C++ set.